# Proc inside ERB

Tags: ruby

There's something weird going on here that I can not understand when I try to implement multiple `content_for` blocks in ERB using plain Ruby.

Here is my code:

```
# helper.rb
require 'erb'

def render(path)
  ERB.new(File.read(path)).result(binding)
end

def content_for(key, &block)
  content_blocks[key.to_sym] = block
end

def yield_content(key)
  content_blocks[key.to_sym].call
end

def content_blocks
  @content_blocks ||= Hash.new
end
```

And template:

```
<% #test.html.erb %>
<% content_for :style do %>
  style
<% end %>
<% content_for :body do %>
  body
<% end %>
<% content_for :script do %>
  script
<% end %>
```

When I open irb to test, I get

```
irb(main):001:0> require './helper'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> render 'test.html.erb'
=> "\n\n\n"
irb(main):003:0> content_blocks
=> {:style=>#<Proc:0x005645a6de2b18@(erb):2>, :body=>#<Proc:0x005645a6de2aa0@(erb):5>, :script=>#<Proc:0x005645a6de2a28@(erb):8>}
irb(main):004:0> yield_content :script
=> "\n\n\n\n  script\n"
irb(main):005:0> yield_content :style
=> "\n\n\n\n  script\n\n  style\n"
```

Why `yield_content :script` got the `\n\n\n` prepended and why `yield_content :style` got the `script\n\n` in result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
ERB.new(File.read(path)).src
```

Then you can see what erb compiles your template to. The template  ends up looking like (formatted for readability)

```
_erbout = ''
_erbout.concat "\n"
#test.html.erb
_erbout.concat "\n"
content_for :style do
  _erbout.concat "\n  style\n"
end
```

Where `_erbout` is the buffer that accumulates the output from your template. `_erbout` is just a local variable,m

When you call your procs they are all just appending to that same buffer, which already contains the result from the template render.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how could I do to make `yield_content :script` outputs only `script`?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe take some inspiration from Rails' inplementation.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to do it after some searching. Just make ERB stores the buffer in other variable instead of `_erbout` by changing `render` function to `ERB.new(File.read(path), nil, nil, "@outbuf").result(binding)`. Then in the `yield_content` function, clear @outbuf before call Proc and it's done. Many thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: You may need to reset the output buffer if there's a way of doing that, or write your own wrapper that handles this by observing what's added to the buffer as the result of that method call.